# JavaFX Using Stage on ViewModel

Tags: java, mvvm, javafx

I need to know when my application is closing. I had implemented this on the start method which starts my JavaFX application:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/ClientWindow.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("ClientWindow");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));

    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest((event) -> {
        // Do my stuff with the service
        service.stopService();
    });
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Now I need to change it to my ViewModel because I need to use the service defined in the start method there. So I had two choices: Either I pass the service object to my ViewModel or I just start it there.
I chose the second answer.

My problem was: How do I know when my window is being closed?
This is what I did in the ViewModel:

```
    // Got a Label object and used it to get the scene and stage. (Ugh.)
    Stage stage = (Stage)this.labelStatus.getScene().getWindow();
    // Set the OnCloseRequest event handler to do what I did in the start() method.
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
        // Stop services

    });
```

So now I am wondering if it's a good idea to do this, because it looks like I am ignoring the idea of the MVVM model. First of all, I need to get the stage using a label (what happens if I don't have a label object on my window or I do not really have to use it on the ViewModel?).

Is this the way I should go or are there better (read: nicer, more direct way) to do this?

**EDIT: Show the FXML where the ModelView is defined**

Look at `fx:controller="viewmodels.ClientWindowViewModel"`

```
<BorderPane minHeight="400.0" minWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="viewmodels.ClientWindowViewModel">
```

Comment: I think passing the service is a better idea. Additionally, I do not understand why is it important for you ViewModel to know when the stage is getting closed.

Comment: Because I need to stop services running when the application is closed, or they will keep running? How can I pass an object from the start method to my ViewModel?

Comment: Where do you create your ViewModel? *I am just to understand how your project is configured.*

Comment: The ViewModel is created inside the FXML File. The ViewModel itself gets instantiated automatically. I will add some code to show you where it gets initialized.

Comment: AFAI understand, you have `root.getController()` will return you the instance of `ClientWindowViewModel`. You can have a method in this class to set the service, `setService(service);` and call it in your start after you have fetched the controller instance.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha there is no root.getController() method.

Comment: My bad, FXMLLoader instance should have that method.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha you're right! This solves my problem. Thanks a lot if you make an answer I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO passing the service to your controller is a better idea.

You can call `FXMLLoader#getController()` which will return you the instance of ClientWindowViewModel. You can have a method in this class to set the service

```
controller.setService(service);
```

and call it in your start after you have fetched the controller instance.

Later when you are trying to close the stage, you can call the same method which you were calling earlier.

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest((event) -> {
   // Do my stuff with the service
   service.stopService();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to follow the MVVM pattern then you should have a look at an application framework which does that right like, e.g. mvvmFX.

https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX

In your setup you are treating the controller as the view model which is wrong. The controller belongs to the view and is sometimes also called "code behind". The view model has a one-to-one relationship with the view but is otherwise independent of it.

If you read the tutorials of mvvmFX you will also learn how to communicate between views and view models which will hopefully answer your question.

Comment: Hello, you're right. This project does not follow the MVVM pattern, because the controller I am using is not a (View-)Model. This project is a lot bigger than it seems and it uses code shared between many other projects. I won't change to an other application framework. My question is how I can know that a view is closing inside of my controller / view model? Or how can I get a stage inside of my controller (or ViewModel). Or how can I pass an object to my Controller (or ViewModel) from the initialization of the View (from which apparently I don't have access to the Controller).

Comment: Well, I think your question has already been answered but for completeness you can always get the stage of a scene like this.         
        Stage stage = (Stage)someNode.getScene().getWindow();
Where someNode can be any node in your scene graph.